# What's a good and simple tool for Scrum Project Management in game development?

Tags: project-management, agile, scrum

I'm looking for an efficient, easy-to-learn tool for Scrum project management not for proffesional use but to use it in my thesis concerning the use of Scrum in game development. Basically I want to visualize a production process of a hypothetical game. Some fragments of the production process should be really detailed to make my point, so basically user stories, tasks, burndown charts etc. are a must.

I'm using Scrum, Kanban and some Lean practices for eliminating waste. I also want to use Extreme Programming practices in this production process including TDD and Continuous Integration.

I have zero experience in proffesional project management so I need something that's fairly simple to use for a newb like me.

Anyone can recommend a tool like that? For now I was thinking about TargetProcess and ScrumWorks. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that scrum for game development is any different than "standard" scrum?

Answer (score 4):

Whiteboards and Post-Its.

No... Seriously.

:-)

Throw in Excel for your charting. This combination is drop dead easy to keep up to date and use.

Brandon

Comment: +1 not just because it is nowadays fashionable to throw out most tools but because in reality - as long as your entire team is co-located this probably works best. Starting with the simplest tools as recommended here is probably going to be the easiest and then you can always see if you need something additional and then decide if something more is needed

Comment: @InSane Agreed. I was going to add that using lightweight systems such as this are more flexible than electronic systems, and you need the flexibility much more when you're just starting out due to the significant learning that's happening. Once your team has found something that works well for you, converting it to an electronic system is pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend these I am familiar with, in this order:

If you are collocated, use whiteboard and Post-its and Excel charting as in the answer above.
If you are not, you may opt for [Trello](http://www.trello.com), which is basically... a whiteboard with post-its. No charting though.

Or [Pivotal Tracker](http://www.pivotaltracker.com), which is aimed specifically to Scrum project management (building some functionality for Kanban, too). It does all the story-points-and-velocity calculations for you and some charting. Somtimes it's too "prescriptive". You don't do Scrum by the book, you might have some difficulties to overcome the built-in lifecycle.

Both are very intuitive and easy-to-use. Trello is free, Pivotal Tracker is free for individual use only. The bigger your team of collaborator the higher the monthly subscription.

Comment: To create charts in Trello, you can use their API https://trello.com/docs/ (which is free to use) or use something like ChartBreeze http://www.chartbreeze.com